# Razor: How to dynamically assign a value to a read only TextBox field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `read-only` text box which is supposed to be initialized to a value dynamically. This field is present on a page which is used to enter values to details corresponding to the player that was created in the previous page (I am using `RedirectToAction()` for this purpose, but was unable to access the passed "`PlayerID`" value from the controller of the current page. So decided on using `TempData`. ). Since the `PlayerID` changes each time a new player is added, this field should display that value while still remaining read-only.
Also, this is a '`required`' field, so the form cannot be submitted until the value is set.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PlayerID, htmlAttributes: new { @readonly = "read-only", @class = "control-label col-md-2", value = @Html.Raw(TempData["PlayerID"]) })
```

How can I set the value of this field as it is in the `TempData["PlayerID"]`?

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` method. You assign the value to the property `PlayerID` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view (and there is no such thing as `@readonly = "control-label col-md-2"` - I assume you want `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PlayerID, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke The `GET` method has following code: `public ActionResult Create() { ViewBag.PlayerID = new SelectList(db.PersonalDetails, "ID", "FirstName"); return View(); }` But the `PlayerID` is not displayed in that read-only text-box. How do I display it?

Comment: A `SelectList` is for use in a dropdownlist (not a textbox)!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just need to display the `PlayerID` of the player created in previous page, and not list the IDs of all the existing players. And need to make it read-only because the user can only add details about existing player and cannot change his ID.

Comment: You need to explain in your question more about what your wanting to do, and the workflow. Your code and comments make no sense without some context. What is this view for, what is the model, what are the controller methods (including the one where you redirected to the method that generated this view. If you previously created a `Player`, then pass its ID to this method and then set the value of the property based on that ID.

Comment: ` @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PlayerID, htmlAttributes: new { @readonly = "read-only", @class = "form - control", Value = Html.Raw(TempData["PlayerID"])})` this worked.

Comment: DO NOT set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods!

Comment: @StephenMuecke why not ? and why a downvote?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125592/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-b-g).

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a JavaScript that runs on the page load, ex:

```
@section Scripts
{
 <script>
   $(function(){
    $("#PlayerID").val('@TempData["PlayerID"]');
   });
 </script>
}
```

Or, you can initialize the Model for the view inside the action, so if your action name was 'PlayerDetails', then you should have something like this:

```
public ActionResult PlayerDetails()
{
  return View(new Player{PlayerID=TempData["PlayerID"]}
}
```

This way, when the view get bound to the view model, it will be initialized to the passed value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
@Html.TextBox("PlayerID", @TempData["PlayerID"] ,new { @readonly = "read-only", @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
```

Or in your case:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PlayerId, htmlAttributes: new { @readonly = "read-only", @class = "control-label col-md-2", Value = @Html.Raw(TempData["PlayerID"]) })
```